# 'Profile' member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type C# 5

Tags: asp.net

I could not find any solution.Any one plz help

The code below is in C# and I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

/**protected System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile Profile {

return ((System.Web.Profile.DefaultProfile)

```
    (this.Context.Profile));
```

**/

```
    public partial class Profile: System.Web.UI.Page

     {

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {

            string css = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrationConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(css))
            {



                SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand("Select * from UserInfm where UserName = '" + Request.Cookies["Login"]["UserName"].ToString() + "' ", conn);

                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (rd.Read())
                    {
                        LabelUN.Text = rd["UserName"].ToString();
                        LabelEM.Text = rd["Email"].ToString();
                        LabelDV.Text = rd["Division"].ToString();
                        LabelMB.Text = rd["MobileNo"].ToString();
                        LabelPA.Text = rd["Password"].ToString();
                      //  LabelFN.Text = rdr["FirstName"].ToString() + " " + rdr["LastName"].ToString();

                        if (rd["User_image"].ToString().Length > 1)
                        {
                            byte[] imgByte = null;
                            imgByte = (byte[])(rd["User_image"]);
                            string str = Convert.ToBase64String(imgByte);
                            Image1.Src = "data:Image/png;base64," + str;



                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Image1.Src = "uploads/default_user.png";

                        }

                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You first check

```
/*

<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="User.aspx.cs" Inherits="User" %>
 */
```

then check

```
public partial class User: System.Web.UI.Page
```